# How to implement page refresh (fetch data from server and losing all changes made) functionality in backbone.js?

Tags: c#, javascript, backbone.js

I am using two views, one original view to show the entire list of items (currently it  shows 3 person's details) and another view is the modal dialog to add a new item to the collection. When I click add in the modal dialog, the new time will populate in the Original view. But I have a button "CancelChanges" in the page and when I click that the Original View must only show the items that were fetched from severe and lose all changes made later. Is there a way I can do that. When I tried to call my Original View ,the page shows a total of 7 person's details. Original 3 items that were fetched from server + the newly added item from modal dialog and it appended 3 original items to that list.Can anyone let me know how to xclear the initial list from the el?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way that come in my mind would be to save your initial models data and then restore them when you click your "Cancel changes" button and re-render your view, something like that:

```
Backbone.View.extend({

initialize: function(){
    _.bindAll(this,'restore_collection');
    this.collection.bind('reset',this.render);
    this.originalModels = this.collection.models;    
},

events: {   
    "click #cancel" : "restore_collection"   
},

restore_collection: function(){   
    this.collection.reset(this.originalModels);    
}
```

Comment: Thanks, its helped me. I also found that it can be done this way by calling empty on my element.

                $(this.el).empty(); 
before I called $(this.el).append(contacts); It helped me restore the collection.